# Ubuntu Linux - Slow printing with lp command

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, printing, lp

I asked here some months ago how to print and check results with lp command (CUPS) in Ubuntu.

After few working around, I was able to print normal text files. I was able to print selecting some options (double sided print, media size, paper tray input, etc.)

I got the linux drivers here (PPD files): https://www.openprinting.org/download/PPD/

Now I have a little problem: When I send a .pdf file to the printer (Ricoh MP Aficio 1106 EX connected by TCP-IP), the print goes slow, getting +30 seconds to send the file to the printer. The .txt files print at the moment I send them. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

I tryied change the socket of the machine to 9100 port, but that only generates errors.

EDIT1:

I tryied using LPR command, instead LP:

`lpr -sPrinterIP /absolute/path/to/file.pdf`

But works slowly too.

EDIT2:

I installed qz-tray, a kind of print server/API. When I try PDF demo, it prints slow too.

EDIT3:
I tryied now with default PDF viewer (EVINCE) because I though I have a lack of memory and printed the same file. It worked well, at normal speed.

EDIT4:
I tyied some other drivers (generic and recomended by the printer maker ones), same speed.

EDIT5:

I found this link: https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Using_Your_Own_Filters_to_Print_with_CUPS

But cannot understand if filtering is "f..king me off", because my printer is a PCL one (and i am using a pxl driver...). Could anyone explain me this?

EDIT 6:

Found the origin of the problem: When I print a text-only-pdf file, it works like a charm. But when I send an image-pdf file, the print enters in a pre-print process (I cannot completely assure this) and get +30seconds to send any package to printer (this checked with wireshark).

I can asume that PPD file (driver file provided by Ricoh Support) has anything in the code that send any order to process the file.

I found this in the PPD file. I think is the root of this slowing problem:

```
*%========== Ghostscript Command line ==========


*FoomaticRIPCommandLine: "(printf &apos;\033%%-12345X@PJL\n@PJL JOB\n@PJL SET COPIES=&copies;\n&apos;%G|perl -p -e &quot;s/\x26copies\x3b/1/&quot;
(gs -q -dBATCH -dPARANOIDSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dNOINTERPOLATE %B%A%C %D%E | perl -p -e &quot;s/^\x1b\x25-12345X//&quot; | perl -p -e &quot;s/\xc1\x01\x00\xf8\x31\x44/\x44/g&quot;
(printf &apos;@PJL\n@PJL EOJ\n\033%%-12345X&apos"
*End
```

Found this article https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/printing-foomatic/2012/002791.html taht confirms my ideas: the ppd driver is rendering all files with ghostcript.

EDIT 7: 
Ricoh support told me that "lp" printing command may be using "default PDF viewer" to process the file, and slow the print process. I don't know how to check it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change the driver. Why? The Recomended RICOH driver for Linux use a not eficient PPD file. This slows the pre-processing of the files. (Windows drivers can use PPD file too, and this slows the process if the file is not optimized)

I used Gutenprint drivers to solve it. The real work now is to get the correct driver for your printers, because Gutenprint drivers doesn't exist for all RICOH machines (and other makers have the smae problem). The 1106EX near-like gutenprint driver is the Aficio MP 1100 driver. But take care when send lp commands: the InputTrays have diferent names.